# Moving space from d: to c: (server 2008)

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning, windows-server-2008, disk-space

I shrinked (using disk management in server 2008) the d: and extracted space of about 6 GB. This extracted space got allocated immediately after d:

Is there a way to extend my c: partition and add this space allocated after the d:. The extend option in this case is not enabled

P.S. *I know Partition magic can do the job. But unfortunately it does not run on server 2008*

Answer (score 3):

While I haven't tried it on a Server 2008 box (yet), I've had good success with [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) for resizing and shuffling partitions. Might be worth a shot?

Comment: isn't if for linux?

Comment: No. You run it from a boot-disk that happens to be linux based. But you run any other partition resizer/manager from a boot-disk as well. 
It recognizes all common partition types regardless of OS

Comment: I would definitely recommend doing this from a boot disk, as you don't want to move possibly in use files on D to move it to the end of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Paragon Partition Manager](http://www.partition-manager.com/)? It has a trial version available, if you want. From what I saw on the site, it has a personal and a server edition, and support for Windows 7 (so I suspect Windows Server 2008 as well).

Answer (score 1):

The partition you wish to expand and the empty space, into which you wish to expand, have to be contiguous.  Currently your D: partition is between them and it needs to be moved.  I couldn't find a way to do that when I was running '08.  You could try one of these partition management products that support Windows Server 2008:

- [Partition Wizard Server Edition](http://partitionwizard.com/partition-manager-server.html)
- [EASEUS Partition Master 4.0.1 Server Edition](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager-server/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only extend *volumes*.

*Basic* disks contain *partitions*. *Dynamic* disks contain *volumes*.

Can you convert c: and d: to both be dynamic disks? If so, you should be able to extend a volume on one to use extra space on the other one.